# Use *.dll instead of *.lib

Tags: visual-c++

I need to integrate third part library to my program. Third party provides header file, dll file and lib file for this purpose. Why do I need lib file? Everything works fine if I use dll and hearer file without using lib one.

Comment: 1) Static linkage (using *.lib file) isn't sometimes acceptable due to license issues. 2) If you use dll's you can deploy new versions of your program just by updating binary file. Third party dll's won't change. 3) Dll's may produce hardly maintaned hell, while lib files are always inside your app and with needed version

Comment: You need a lib even when linking dynamically to the DLL otherwise your compilation will fail during linking (it needs to match up the import and export tables). Maybe the header file has a `#pragma` that imports the lib, otherwise I can't see how it can build. @Pie_Jesu comment regarding static lib is also valid, you may have a static lib instead of a DLL but whichever way you go, you always need a lib.